# Ruby Bundle Install Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not able to bundle install Ruby On Rails. I am getting the error

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
(RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/sites/rails_projects/sample_app/with-ffi_c-lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/sites/rails_projects/sample_app/with-ffi_c-lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing ffi (1.0.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'` succeeds before bundling.
PS C:\sites\rails_projects\sample_app>
```

when I try running `gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'`

I get the error

```
"ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'ffi-v' <>=0 in any repository
```

I have searched around on google and some people think that I need to install the ruby devkit to fix this issue. The problem is, I can't get this to work either. I run the ruby dk.rb init command, and the initialization completes, but when I look in the config.yml file, there are no rubies automatically listed, although I have ruby installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The second error is because you mis-typed the gem install command. Specifically, you omitted the space between 'ffi' and '-v'

Comment: The problem is indeed the devkit. The bundler error tells you this. It's failing because one of the gems you're trying to install (ffi) requires native extensions to be compiled on your OS in order to work. Without the devkit, this fails. I recommend you post all the output you get when you install the devkit.

Comment: PS C:\sites\rails_projects\sample_app> gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

These are the errors I get when I try installing ffi with the correct syntax, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: So now my question is, if no rubies are populated in the config.yml file when I initialize the devkit installer, how can I get the devkit to install correctly?